# Is there a .gemrc.local or equivalent?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Like many people I created a dotfiles repo and am trying extract bits that are not private into their respective dotfiles. I generally have a `.whatever.local` file loaded if it's present which might contain information I don't want checked into a repository. Rubygems use `~/.gemrc` file, but I can't see a way to extract private information out of it into separate file. Does anyone know how this might be done?

In particular I'd like to have the list of `sources` external to the .gemrc file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not see an equivalent to `.local` as per v2.4.6 (a recent, but not last version).

The source code of RubyGems states something relevant for what you want to achieve, though. For example, in `src/ruby-2.3.0/lib/rubygems/config_file.rb`:

```
##
# Gem::ConfigFile RubyGems options and gem command options from gemrc.
#
# gemrc is a YAML file that uses strings to match gem command arguments and
# symbols to match RubyGems options.
#
# Gem command arguments use a String key that matches the command name and
# +:sources+:: Sets Gem::sources
# +:verbose+:: See #verbose
#
# gemrc files may exist in various locations and are read and merged in
# the following order:
#
# - system wide (/etc/gemrc)
# - per user (~/.gemrc)
# - per environment (gemrc files listed in the GEMRC environment variable)
```

So you could use the `GEMRC` environment variable to load extra, private files as well.

Comment: This works. Though, one annoying thing is that you have to repeat all the listing of all :sources: in the file pointed to by GEMRC the values in this file overwrite the current settings (though I can understand why they've done it that way).

Comment: Yes, it works by file... All or nothing for each file. Perhaps there is little demand so far for finer granularity?

Comment: I literally took a look at coding something up, but given that this question doesn't seem to have come up before decided it was probably a very rare requirement.